# Getting an image overlay/class to show onclick depending on the class of a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I was just assigned my first project for work and am having some trouble with the last details.

Essentially, when a user clicks a list item in a class of "answerPick" is added to the li. When the user clicks another li item to change their answer the class of "answerPick" is removed from the first choice and added to the new choice. At the end of the form, the user submits and I take all values attached to li items with a class of "answerPick".

Here is an example of the structure of one of the form questions:

```
<!--Section B-->
  <section id="section-b" class="grid">
    <div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="section-question">
    <img src="/Images/modules/GiftThemeHeader_418x50.jpg">
 </div>
      <ul class="answer-options-grid">
        <li class="answer" data-url="relaxation"><img src="/Images/modules/Relaxation_200x150.jpg" class="baseimg"> <img src="/Images/modules/Check1Mobile.png" class="topimg">Relaxation</li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="skincare"><img src="/Images/modules/BodyCare_200x150.jpg" class="baseimg"> <img src="/Images/modules/Check1Mobile.png" class="topimg">Body Care</li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="date-night"><img src="/Images/modules/DateNight_200x150.jpg" class="baseimg"> <img src="/Images/modules/Check1Mobile.png" class="topimg">Date Night</li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="at-home-spa"><img src="/Images/modules/Spa_200x150.jpg" class="baseimg"> <img src="/Images/modules/Check1Mobile.png" class="topimg">At-home spa </li>
      </ul>
</div>
    </section>
```

You'll notice I have an image called "Check1Mobile" right next to the selected image. This image is automatically hidden via .hide().

Basically what I'm trying to do is have the check image show using .show(), when the li item is clicked and is given the class "answerPick". I'm trying to only target specific instances of the class "topimg" during the click function because I use that image/class for each of the form questions.

Here is a snippet of code. I can include everything but I am a javascript scrub so it is messy, to be honest.

```
  $jq('.answer img').click(function () {
if ((this).parent().hasClass('answerPick')) {
  $jq('.topimg').show();
}
else {
  $jq('.topimg').hide();
} });
```

Comment: to make `parent()` work in jQuery context, you need it wrapped inside `$`, So `$(this).parent()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dhaval. When the user clicks one of the li items answerPick is automatically added. 

So for the if statement would it look like `if((this).parent().hasClass('answerPick')) {`

Comment: That would be `if($(this).parent().....` OR  `if($jq(this).parent().....`

Comment: Much appreciated Louys! Are you aware of anyway for me to target and show/hide, one specific instance of a class attached to multiple images? I think that may be my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the piece of code you have written it should be:

```
$jq('.answer img').click(function () {
  $jq('.topimg').hide()

  if ($jq(this).parent().hasClass('answerPick')) {
    $jq(this)('.topimg').show();
  }
});
```

But I can also suggest :

```
  $jq('.answer img').on('click', function () {
      const el = $jq(this)

      el.parent().find('.topimg')
      el.find('.topimg').toggle(el.hasClass('answerPick'))
   });
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/190257/) for live example.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Laura. I actually tried both and the checkmark images were still not showing when li options were clicked and gained the class of answerPick. Would it be helpful if i just posted a jsfiddle with the entire coding in it? Nothing too long its just 4 questions some styling and JS code behind it.

Comment: Can you give me the code you're using to add the `.answerPick` class so I can be as close as possible from your original code ? Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, Are you aware of anyway for me to target and show/hide, one specific instance of a class attached to multiple images? I think that may be my issue because topimg is applied to hidden checkmark overlays across the page.

Comment: For example hide/show the `topimg` of the `li` you have clicked ?

Comment: Sure. one moment

Comment: Another question @JoeG do you hide your `topimg` when the page is loaded ? Like `$jq('.topimg').hide()`

Comment: Yes I have  `$jq('.topimg').hide();` right at the top of the code after 
`$jq(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/187989/ here's a jsfiddle with the new code, let me know if it corresponds to what you are looking for as behaviour so I can update my main answer and we put it as resolved.

Comment: Somewhat. The thing is I want to be able to show the check image in specific spots (places that the user has clicked). With your fiddle they are all shown at once. Hopefully I'm making sense.

Comment: @JoeG I have edited my jsfiddle following your request

Comment: Unfortunately I want to only reveal the `<img src="/Images/modules/Check1Mobile.png" class="topimg">` when I click on that answer option. As it is now, (like in your fiddle) all of them are revealed. I'm starting to think Its not possible the way I have this setup. I thought I could use $(this) but I may have been mistaken.

Comment: @JoeG I think you are checking the wrong version of the jsfiddle, this is the most recent one https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/188371/

Comment: Just took a look and it looks like it works! Thank you. I don't want to bother you anymore but could you explain how it works? Im not seeing where in the code you tell topimg to show itself

Comment: I have update the link in my main answer if you want to take a look I have add comment to explain. (also close your question if possible ;) )